# How to create custom link with external URL and conditional logic

Tags: custom-url

I need to create a custom link to pricing pages in our external systems.  we have several different systems we use depending on the clients needs.  we capture the system and account ID in our SFDC.  the 2 url's I am working with are as follows....
https://my.gss.com/mvp/includes/printClientPricing.cfm?ID=**HCR3691**
https://app.visionary.com/admin/clients/**80**/edit#PricingAndPackages

I can pass the ID to the first url easy enough but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the ID to the second url which is the bold number between backslahes.

my formula is as follows.

```
{!IF(INCLUDES( Account.Platform__c , "GSS Davuirus") ,
     URLFOR("https://my.gss.com/mvp/includes/printClientPricing.cfm", null, 
           [ID= Account.Platform_Client_ID__c ]) , 
     IF(INCLUDES( Account.Platform__c , "visionary"),
        "https://app.visionary.com/admin/clients/"& Account.Platform_Client_ID__c &  
        "/edit#PricingAndPackages" ,
        null) )}
```

the first if statement works perfect but i'm not sure how to approch the second if statement.

Comment: and `URLFOR("https://app.visionary.com/admin/clients/"& Account.Platform_Client_ID__c &  
        "/edit#PricingAndPackages",null)` doesn't work?

Comment: You are missing URLFOR( in the second part. Could that be it? Are you getting an error on save? If no error, what is the URL that you get from this formula?